# How do I find the line a word is on when the user enters text in Perl?

Tags: perl, find

I have a simple text file that includes all 50 states. I want the user to enter a word and have the program return the line the specific state is on in the file or otherwise display a "word not found" message. I do not know how to use find. Can someone assist with this? This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/perl -w

open(FILENAME,"<WordList.txt");             #opens WordList.txt
my(@list) = <FILENAME>;                     #read file into list
my($state);                                 #create private "state"     variable
print "Enter a US state to search for: \n"; #Print statement
$line = <STDIN>;                            #use of STDIN to read input from user


close (FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative solution that reads only the parts of the file until a result is found, or the file is exhausted:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

print "Enter a US state to search for: \n";
my $line = <STDIN>;
chomp($line);

# open file with 3 argument open (safer)
open my $fh, '<', 'WordList.txt'
   or die "Unable to open 'WordList.txt' for reading: $!";

# read the file until result is found or the file is exhausted
my $found = 0;
while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {
   chomp($row);
   next unless $row eq $line;

   # $. is a special variable representing the line number 
   # of the currently(most recently) accessed filehandle
   print "Found '$line' on line# $.\n"; 
   $found =  1;  # indicate that you found a result
   last;         # stop searching
}
close($fh);

unless ( $found ) { 
   print "'$line' was not found\n";
}
```

General notes:

- always `use strict;` and `use warnings;` they will save you from a wide range of bugs
- 3 argument open is generally preferred, as well as the `or die ...` statement. If you are unable to open the file, reading from the filehandle will fail
- $. documentation can be found in [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles)

Comment: Indeed. `while` is also preferable to slurping in an array for memory reasons generally. Of course, if you're  doing the job twice, then it's a different sort of tradeoff.

Comment: The standard approach so ++

Answer (score 1):

Tool for the job is `grep`.

```
 chomp ( $line ); #remove linefeeds 
 print "$line is in list\n" if grep { m/^\Q$line\E$/g } @list;
```

You could also transform your `@list` into a hash, and test that, using `map`:

```
 my %cities = map { $_ => 1 } @list; 
 if ( $cities{$line} ) { print "$line is in list\n";}
```

Note - the above, because of the presence of `^` and `$` is an exact match (and case sensitive). You can easily adjust it to support fuzzier scenarios.

Comment: `\Q` might be needed, and a newline in print.